# Pass date input string to cell range

Tags: string, excel, date, vba

I am trying to pass the date entered in this input box through a range of cells in a specific column. The range isn't specific but must fill all the cells that currently contain data in that column.

```
'Date input box
    Sub dateInput()
        Dim dateString As String, TheDate As Date
        dateString = Application.InputBox("Enter Certificate Date")
        If IsDate(dateString) Then
            TheDate = DateValue(dateString)
        Else
            MsgBox "That's not good!"
        End If
    End Sub
```

This is as far as I've gotten, but I can't seem to feed the entered date into the range of cells.

Comment: What does `pass through a range of cells` mean?  Can you provide an example of expected output?  Are you just overwriting the existing data within cells?

Comment: What range of cells?  Soemthing like `Range("A1:A10").Value = TheDate` should do it...

Comment: If you are looking to ignore blanks in *a range of cells in a specific column* then use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx).

Comment: @Byron - You are on the right track. Overwriting the current data is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: All the answers put the value somewhere.  If you want to only touch cells with existing data (avoid blanks maybe), you can use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Value = TheDate` where `Range` is defined in the various ways people are doing down below.  I don't want to add a 4th nearly identical answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following sample to replace all the non empty cells in the range with the date:

```
Sub dateInput()
    Dim dateString As String, TheDate As Date
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<-- Workbook you are working in
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet '<-- Worksheet you are working in


    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then '<-- Finding last row used
            LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
             '<-- Finding last column used
            LastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            LastCol = 1 '<-- Selecting first column if nothing found
            LastRow = 1 '<-- Selecting first row if nothing found
        End If
    End With

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)) '<-- You can set your range here

    dateString = Application.InputBox("Enter Certificate Date")
    If IsDate(dateString) Then
        TheDate = DateValue(dateString)

        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c.Value <> "" Then
                c.Value = TheDate
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "That's not good!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I set the range to fill cells with data. I don't necessarily want it to stop at B10. Make sense?

Comment: I think you already got your answer below but if you still have problems please let me know.

Comment: Based on your answer above, I would like to know how to set that range to go from A1:? - meaning set the end range to unlimited so that it carries through all cells that contain data.

Comment: sorry for late reply. Please see updated code to find and use all the used range in the worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

This will allow the user to pick the column:

```
Sub dateInput()
        Dim dateString As String, TheDate As Date, r As Range
        dateString = Application.InputBox("Enter Certificate Date")
        If IsDate(dateString) Then
            TheDate = DateValue(dateString)
        Else
            MsgBox "That's not good!"
        End If

   Set r = Application.InputBox("O.K.  Now pick a column", Type:=8)
   For Each rr In Intersect(r, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      If rr.Value <> "" Then
         rr.Value = TheDate
      End If
   Next rr
End Sub
```

Comment: Like this one most.  Could replace the loop with a `r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Value = TheDate` and get rid of `Intersect` also.  That assumes there are no formulas and current data is `Constant` but that seems safe-ish.

Answer (score 1):

You have some logic wrong so i fixed it, ie using dateString but no declaration and checking it when no value was set (assuming you fixed it as it is no longer showing in your code).  Other than that you just need to define the range and set the value.  Example below

```
Sub dateInput()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Cells.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 1))


    Dim TheString As String, TheDate As Date
    TheString = Application.InputBox("Enter Certificate Date")
    If IsDate(TheString) Then
        TheDate = DateValue(TheString)
    Else
        MsgBox "That's not good!"
    End If

    r.Value = TheDate
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I set the range to cover all the cells with data. I don't want to leave it at just those 10 cells... Make sense?